# access denied for administrator in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I've installed SharePoint Server 2010 on my Windows Server 2008. Everything went smoth until i should config SharePoint 2010.
I can't login to Central administration or any sites.
I have checked my sp_admin account and its a domain account and members of administrators, domains admin, domain users, IIS_IUSRS, performance monitor users and WSS_WPG.

In my logfile I see
04/19/2012 13:27:20.26  w3wp.exe (0x0B04)   0x090C  SharePoint Foundation   General 94vw    Medium  Primary Domain = DEV, Computer Name = WINSERVER2008R2

04/19/2012 13:27:27.89  w3wp.exe (0x0EB8)   0x156C  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (GET:http://winserver2008r2:8080/default.aspx) 61c23c87-304f-4084-a124-e39b028b74af

One of my friends said that i should config something in the host file?

I seek high and low for this issue. But didn't find a solution for my problem.

Can anyone of you guys help me.

TIA

Comment: Can you be more specific? If I understand correctly you have installed the binaries, ran the configuration wizard and then could not access the central admin?

Comment: Thats exactly whats happen - I can't get access to Central Admin - Please let me know if i can provide you with some more info. please specify which info you want. I'm a kind of newbie in this sharepoint univers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try accessing the sites from another machine.  If that works then you have what is known as the "Loopback Issue" on your sharepoint machine and can follow [these steps](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861) to correct it.  Method 2 is what usually works best.

Comment: Hi Dave
Thanks for your suggestions
I've only have this PC and i'm using VMware for my development
Neither of these methods work - i'm still haven't access denied. Any other suggestions - What can i check to se if my configuration is correct (AD users - Configuration of server etc)

Comment: Sorry for my bad english - i have not access to central admin

Comment: Did you install sharepoint using the sp_admin account or another one?  If you used a different account, try logging in and accessing central admin with that account

Comment: Lucky me I've installed it on a linked clone. I'll reinstall SP2010. But for geting it right - I have created 3 users in AD, sp_admin,sp_farm and sp_sqlservice. sp_admin account is a domain account and members of administrators, domains admin, domain users, IIS_IUSRS, performance monitor users and WSS_WPG. Is this correct. Any other things to remember before I install SP2010

Comment: there is a very detailed document that explains all of the service accounts purposes and permissions here : http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/sp2010security/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=5245

Comment: Hi Dave
That was really a helpfull link.
That solve my problem. I have used a wrong account
Thank you